# In Selenium with Java, how can I wait for all the backend process to be completed and then execute the next command?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my project there are lots of backend process running and because of which my test cases are passing sometimes and sometimes they are failing. Is there a way in Selenium where I can wait for all the backend process to be completed and then execute the next command?

Answer (score 2):

I've generally found Selenium to be unreliable with waiting for events etc. I always find the sleeping for "enough time" is the best and most reliable approach.

I generally define "enough time" as twice the longest observed time.

Selenium tests are slow anyway. I believe making them 100% reliable at the cost of a bit more slowness is worth the trade off.